# PowerShell File Path for Readyshare

Tags: powershell, t-sql, excel-2010

Specification:

1. OS Windows 10
2. SQL Server 2012

Languages and software used:

1. Powershell
2. Excel 2010

Code:

```
 #Define locations and delimiter
 $csv = "\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile.csv" #Location of the source file
 $xlsx = "\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile2.xlsx" #Desired location of output
 $delimiter = "," #Specify the delimiter used in the file

 # Create a new Excel workbook with one empty sheet
 $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
 $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
 $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

 # Build the QueryTables.Add command and reformat the data
 $TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv)
 $Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
 $query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
 $query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter
 $query.TextFileParseType  = 1
 $query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,1 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
 $query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

 # Execute & delete the import query
 $query.Refresh()
 $query.Delete()

 # Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
 $Workbook.SaveAs($xlsx,51)
 $excel.Quit()
```

Job error:
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$Server. ...l.exe -file "C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1"Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile2.csv'. There are several   possible reasons:   The file name or path does not exist.   The file is being used by another program.   The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:12 char:1  + $Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFilePath)  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:13 char:1  + $Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:21 char:1  + Out-File -FilePath C:\Scripts\process.txt -InputObject $Columns.Cells ...  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:22 char:1  + Write-Host $Columns.Cells(5,5).Value  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:161 char:1  + $eRow = $Worksheet.cells.item(1,1).entireRow  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:162 char:1  + $active = $eRow.activate()  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:163 char:1  + $active = $eRow.insert($xlShiftDown)  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:164 char:1  + $Worksheet.Cells.item(1,1) = "TRANSACTION_DATE"  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:165 char:1  + $Worksheet.Cells.item(1,2) = "AMOUNT"  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:166 char:1  + $Worksheet.Cells.item(1,3) = "TYPE_OF_AUTHORIZATION_AND_DATE"  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At C:\Scripts\trasaction.ps1:167 char:1  + $Worksheet.Cells.item(1,4) = "CHECK_NUMBER"  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot ...  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

Things that were tried.

1. giving perminsions for the SqlServerAgent. Which readyshare will not let me do.
2. making the file path with powershell script name in to a bat file to be executed from the C: drive to get into the file path.

Notes:

This powershell script runs great from the command prompt by manually opening up cmd and executing. Even works great from the ISE (x86) manually.

However, when using this from a job you get the error listed above.

I have tried to get the readyshare drive to give SQLSeverAgent permissions but reverts back to original permissions. The router I have is a nightHawk router
and I didn't see any setting with in the router to give permissons either tried through Windows 10 but reverts back to original permissions.

Checked these suggestion from the message

- The file name or path does not exist.
- The file is being used by another program.
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

None applied.

Is there any work around or option I may not know about? Need some guidance or pointer in the right direction.

Comment: I see the code didn't go in right so the this part is part of the powershell script see below

Comment: #Define locations and delimiter $csv = "\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile.csv" #Location of the source file $xlsx = "\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile2.xlsx" #Desired location of output $delimiter = "," #Specify the delimiter used in the file

Comment: Is there a typo in the error message?? I see it mentions user `NT Service\SQLAgent$SEVER` where in your description you mention the user that is running the job `SQLSeverAgent`. Also, please Close the workbook and worksheet before quitting excel and after quitting Release the com objects. `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-NUll; [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null; [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: Also the error message states `$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFilePath)` but in the code given i cannot find that anywhere..

Comment: Thanks marc_s for correcting……….

Comment: I think I pasted the wrong error message there are three powershell scripts that I get the same results let me correct the error message.

Comment: Ok got the right error in there. Like I said I have 3 different jobs with the  different scripts going to the same path getting the same error. I have tried writing output code to the file to see if I see anything out of the ordinary I know excel is instantiated correctly because the output will show the objects in the output text file. I see it getting stuck at opening I know the file is in the correct path tried several times.

Comment: Also something I did forget to mention this is a 32bit excel.

Comment: variations of the file path I have tried are v:\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile.csv, v:\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile.csv, v:\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile.csv

Comment: Theo let me try what you said will follow up...….. Closing out com

Comment: Please check and recheck the filenames you are using. The error now states `Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile2.csv'` but your code says `\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Trucking_Inc\SomeFile.csv`

Comment: Ok added suggested code Theo. However, not sure if that is going to prevent the code from opening up the excel and changing the file. Going to run the job see if there are any changes.

Comment: I  see what your saying...

Comment: Ok did what was suggested: I don't think its a file path issue but memory or disk space according to the error on the job. see below:

Comment: Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$Server. ...l.exe -file "C:\Scripts\Untitled4.ps1"Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.    To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need.    To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.  At C:\Scripts\Untitled4.ps1:8 char:1  + $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)  thinking this is because of this line 8. The share drive is 115GB in size.